# Getting several childs having the same names for each element of a given XML using the Apache Pig tool (Hadoop)

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, apache-pig, nested-loops

I would like to gett several childs having the same names for each element of a given XML using Pig but it won't work...

I have this XML:

```
<A>
    <B> 
        <C>valueC1</C>
        <D>
            <E>valueE1</E>
            <F>
                <G>valueG11</G>
                <H>valueH11</H>
            </F>
            <F>
                <G>valueG12</G>
                <H>valueG12</H>
            </F>
            <F>
                <G>valueG13</G>
                <H>valueG13</H> 
            </F>
        </D>
    </B>
    <B> 
        <C>valueC2</C>
        <D>
            <E>valueE1<E>
            <F>
                <G>valueG21</G>
                <H>valueH21</H>
            </F>
            <F>
                <G>valueG22</G>
                <H>valueH22</H>
            </F>
            <F>
                <G>valueG23</G>
                <H>valueH23</H> 
            </F>
        </D>
    </B>
</A>
```

I would like to have:

```
(valueC1, valueE1,(valueG11,valueG12,valueG13))
(valueC2, valueE2,(valueG21,valueG22,valueG23))
```

I tried:

```
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();
A = LOAD '/user/hue/maelia/adhesions_xml/MMC.20140214.xml' 
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('B') as    (x:chararray); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'), XPath(x,'B/D/E'),XPath(x,'B/D/F/G');
C = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'), XPath(x,'B/D/E'),XPath(x,'B/D/F[0]/G');
D = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'), XPath(x,'B/D/E'),XPath(x,'B/D/F[position()=0]/G');
E = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'), XPath(x,'B/D/E'),XPath(x,'B/D/F[1]/G');
F = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'), XPath(x,'B/D/E'),XPath(x,'B/D/F[position()=1]/G');
dump B;
dump C;
dump D;
dump E;
dump F;
```

It returns:

```
(valueC1, valueE1,valueG11)
(valueC2, valueE2,valueG21)
```

or:

```
(valueC1, valueE1,)
(valueC2, valueE2,)
```

And I tried then:

```
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();
A = LOAD '/user/.../sample.xml' 
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('B') as (x:chararray); 
B = FOREACH A {
LOAD '/user/.../sample.xml' 
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader(
        CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                'B/C[text()=\'',
                x
             ),
             '\']/../D/F/G'
         )
     ) as (y:chararray);
GENERATE XPath(x,'B/C'),y;
};
dump C
```

It returns an error:

```
...ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error    during parsing. <file script.pig, line 5, column 9>  mismatched input   ''/user/.../sample.xml'' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Failed to parse: <file script.pig, line 5, column 9>  mismatched input      ''/user/.../sample.xml'' expecting LEFT_PAREN
at     org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:244)
...
```

Someone have any idea to solve this issue?
However, can we make a load into a nested foreach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved it adding '//' on the beggining of the xpath. Hope that will help :)